# How does android bootloader know it has to boot from Slot B?

Tags: android-source, android-kernel

After the OTA update is successful, AOSP marks the target slot B to active. Now, when the next boot happens, the device boots from slot B. Now my question is how does the bootloader or android come to know it has to boot from that active slot?
Does it read from any ro property or from something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is manufacturer/vendor specific and not specified by Android. A vendor has to provide an implementation of the `android.hardware.boot@1.0` HAL in which he has to decide how to implement the `setActiveBootSlot` call coming from the `update_engine`.

The `bootloader` (also provided by the vendor) then has to implement means to get the active boot slot.

A vendor could for example decide to store the current active boot slot in the `/misc` partition

See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement.html

Comment: This ro.boot.slot_suffix is only be modified by kernel cmdline argument.and its value is set by kernel cmdline property ie androidboot.slot_suffix